# Can someone help me point out my error here?

Tags: python

```
def target(heart):

    age = input("Enter your age: ")
    rest_heart = input("Enter your resting heart rate: ")
    intensity = input("Enter your heart intensity: ")
    max_heart = 220 - age
    reserve = max_heart - rest_heart
    return rest_heart + intensity * reserve

print(target(heart))
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>

NameError: name 'heart' is not defined
```

If someone could point out the error, that'd be greatly appreciated

Comment: where are you using `heart` that you are passing to the function? where in `main` are you declaring the variable `heart`?

Comment: just like it says ``heart`` is not defined. use ``print(target(0))`` instead. Btw your function never uses the parameter, so it would make no difference if you do ``target(0)`` or ``target(None)`` or ``target("Hello World")`` ...

Answer (score 5):

You didn't declared the variable `heart` in your code.

Here, the `heart` in `target(heart)` is useless because you try to pass a parameter to a function that doesn't use it.

Also, you call your function with `print(target(heart))` but you didn't set `heart` in this scope, it could work if you put `heart = 0` (or anything) above your code but this parameter will still be useless.

Answer (score 2):

Simply answering your question wouldn't really help you since one day or another you will need to know how to handle your errors by yourself.. In this context i'm offering you this [tutorial](https://www.sololearn.com/Course/Python/) which will teach you python appropriately with applications.

However, the problem of your script is that you're trying to call a variable `heart` you didn't create in the first place.

Also, like others pointed out, passing `heart` as a parameter is useless since you're not using it inside your function.

As a conclusion, I advise you to follow the guide provided above.
Hope this was somehow helpfull.